# No route matches [POST] "/contacts/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

app/view/contact/show.html/erb

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Firstname:</b>
  <%= @contact.firstname %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Lastname:</b>
  <%= @contact.lastname %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= @contact.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Mobilephone:</b>
  <%= @contact.mobilephone %>
</p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> |
<%= link_to 'List', contacts_path %>
```

in my view/contact/index.html.erb i have a button

```
<%= button_to 'show', contact %>
```

in my contacts_controller.rb i just use automatic setting like:

```
def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contact }
    end
  end
```

in my routes file

```
match '/contacts/:id/edit', :controller => 'contacts', :action => 'edit'
  match '/contacts/contact_:id/show', :controller => 'contacts', :action => 'show'
  resources :contacts
  resources :connections
  resources :addresses
  root :to => 'contacts#index'
```

and after running rake routes i got

```
/contacts/:id/edit(.:format)    contacts#edit
                       /contacts/:id/show(.:format)    contacts#show
       contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)             contacts#index
                POST   /contacts(.:format)             contacts#create
    new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)         contacts#new
   edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)    contacts#edit
        contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#show
                PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#update
                DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)         contacts#destroy
    connections GET    /connections(.:format)          connections#index
                POST   /connections(.:format)          connections#create
 new_connection GET    /connections/new(.:format)      connections#new
edit_connection GET    /connections/:id/edit(.:format) connections#edit
     connection GET    /connections/:id(.:format)      connections#show
                PUT    /connections/:id(.:format)      connections#update
                DELETE /connections/:id(.:format)      connections#destroy
      addresses GET    /addresses(.:format)            addresses#index
                POST   /addresses(.:format)            addresses#create
    new_address GET    /addresses/new(.:format)        addresses#new
   edit_address GET    /addresses/:id/edit(.:format)   addresses#edit
        address GET    /addresses/:id(.:format)        addresses#show
                PUT    /addresses/:id(.:format)        addresses#update
                DELETE /addresses/:id(.:format)        addresses#destroy
           root        /                               contacts#index
```

And when i click the button 'show'   i got Routes Error   No route matches [POST] "/contacts/1"    Could somebody help me checking what mistake i have maken,please?  Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's easier if you use the standard routing offered by `resources contacts` - then you could simply use `<%= link_to 'show', contact_path(contact) %>`

Also, the button should perform a GET request, not a POST since that route is not defined.

If I were you I would remove the first two custom routes you declared and just rely on the `resources :contacts` method instead. This in combination with a GET request should fix your problem.

Comment: What if you try `<%= link_to 'show', contact_path(contact) %>`

Comment: Oh  it works !!thanks!   but  why???  button looks better and isnt it just a style format?

Comment: You can style the link as a button - with `twitter bootstrap` this is dead easy. And the reason it works is because your routes file declares a GET request, not a POST. If you are insisting on using a POST, you should add that route to the routes file. See here for more info on how:http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes